# Regex for (+918047093311) or (+918061914444 PIN 6251)

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a regex for extracting a +91XXXXXXXXXX or 0XXXXXXXXX from the string  (+918047093311) or (+918061914444 PIN 6251) or (08061914444 PIN 6251).

I want to read inside the bracket and fetch the number with +91 or 0 followed by 10 digit starting only from 9,8,7 and 6.

So far I was able to make this -> `^([0]|\+91)?[6789]\d{9}$`

This is able to detect a number starting from +91 or 0 then 10 digit number starting from 6,7,8 or 9.

Please help

Comment: What does the regex not do that you want it to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
(?:\b0|\+91)?[6-9]\d{9}\b
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/Ph4tAI/1/). The expression matches zero or `+91` as an optional value, then a digit from `6789` set, then nine digits.

Java:

```
String s = "(+918047093311) or (+918061914444 PIN 6251) or (08061914444 PIN 6251)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:\b0|\\+91)?[6-9]\\d{9}\\b");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group()); 
}
```

Output:

```
+918047093311
+918061914444
8061914444
```

Answer (score 1):

for your definition, this should work

```
$ echo "I am trying to write a regex for extracting a +91XXXXXXXXXX or 0XXXXXXXXX from the string (+918047093311) or (+918061914444 PIN 6251) or (08061914444 PIN 6251)." | 
  grep -oE '(?<=\()?(0|\+91)?[6-9][0-9]{9}(?=( |\)))?'
```

gives

```
+918047093311
+918061914444
08061914444
```